# Is there any significance to the "shiki" most Otsutsuki have in their names?

Tags: naruto, boruto

Well... the title says it all!

Most of the Otsutsuki clan members, if not all to appear in Boruto have "shiki" at the end of their names. Examples would be Momo**shiki** Otsutsuki, Kin**shiki** Otsutsuki, Ura**shiki** Otsutsuki (filler), and Is**shiki** Otsutsuki.  There are indeed some Otsutsuki without shiki in their names, such as Ashura, Indra, Kaguya, Hagoromo, Hamura, and more. However it raised my eyebrow when almost all Otsutsuki in Boruto had "shiki" in the end of their name, so I wondered if it has any significance.

So, is there *any* significance to the "shiki" most Otsutsuki have in their names? If so, what is it?

Comment: Not sure if related, however according to Google Translate from Japanese to English, “Shiki” is roughly translated to “Four Seasons”. Based on your question and wiki, I count a total of four Otsutsuki members (anime and manga) with the suffix “Shiki”. So I’m wondering if each one represents a season (Sping, Summer, Fall, and Winter)?

Comment: Ah, makes sense. I also went to Google Translate to find the meaning of shiki, translating to four seasons, however Japanese translate is *very* inaccurate there so I came here for the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The characters mentioned are all based on Japanese folklore. The original names of the folklore characters are Momotaro, Kintaro, Urashima Taro, and Issun Kotaro. -Taro is just a common way to end boy's names, similar to -maru. In Naruto, the characters were named by taking the first two syllables and add -shiki to the end. The exact significance of -shiki in Naruto is still unknown, if there is any ([There are several meanings of -shiki in Japanese depending on context](https://www.quora.com/In-Japanese-what-is-the-meaning-of-shiki), but I don't what is the context in Naruto). Some of the Otsutsuki mythological references are pretty obscure, so it is hard to know.

Also, there is also a theory proposed by a redditor that the -shiki suffix us given *only to the main members* of the Otsutsuki clan.

Source:

1. https://www.reddit.com/r/Boruto/comments/ich72h/why_does_almost_every_otsusuki_has_shiki_in_their/
2. https://www.reddit.com/r/Naruto/comments/e0an6d/theory_the_shiki_names_are_only_given_to_members/